# Using IQueryable Where with Expressions with more than one parameter

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, c#-3.0

I am using LINQ to Entities and querying for entries within a certain date time period, held in  model object which has the properties `DateFrom` and `DateTo`.  To do this I can use the following to create a sequence

```
var allActiveLogs = this.repository.RoutePerformanceLogs
         .Where(log => log.Date >= model.DateFrom.Value && 
                log.Date <= model.DateTo.Value)
```

If I want to abstract this out for reuse I can create the following expression (as long model is in scope).

```
Expression<Func<RoutePerformanceLog, bool>> logWithinDateBounds = log => 
        log.Date >= model.DateFrom.Value && log.Date <= model.DateTo.Value;
```

and then later call

```
var allActiveLogs = this.repository.RoutePerformanceLogs.Where(logWithinDateBounds)
```

What I would like to do is abstract this expression further, to code where model is not in scope, possibly using an expression of signature

```
Expression<Func<RoutePerformanceLog, DateTime?, DateTime?, bool>> logWithinDateBounds
```

However, this won't work within a Where method, as the where method requires a `Func<T, boolean>` or an `Expression<Func<T, boolean>>`.

Is it possible to have a reusable expression, that takes more than one parameter and can be used to filter an `IQueryable` collection (preferably using the query provider to do the filtering rather than filtering objects in memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this can help. It is a quite functional programming approach. You can create a function (or an Expression) returning a function and using that function for the Where.

Something like the following:

```
Func<int, int, Func<int,bool>> func = (x, y) => z=> x + y > z;
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

Console.WriteLine("How many greater than 2+1? {0}", 
                  list.Where(func(1, 2)).Count());
Console.WriteLine("How many greater than 3+1? {0}", 
                  list.Where(func(3, 1)).Count());
Console.WriteLine("How many greater than 2+3? {0}", 
                  list.Where(func(2, 3)).Count());
Console.ReadKey();
```

In your case you need:

```
Func<DateTime, DateTime, Expression<Func<RoutePerformanceLog, bool>>> logWithinDateBounds =         
    (dateFrom, dateTo) => 
       log => log.Date >= dateFrom && log.Date <= dateTo;
```